# Why Autofac can't resolve this dependency?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

The error message I'm getting is

> 2016-09-14 18:55:12,276 INFO 
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver - Failed to process
>   message Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the
>   constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'ProjectServices.EsbHandlers.NewProcessMessageHandler' can be invoked
>   with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'ProjectServices.Cache.ICachedNotificationsStorage
>   cachedNotificationsStorage' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Project.Model.IRepository,
>   Project.Model.Services.ICaseDelegationService,
>   Priject.Model.Services.IDocumentDelegationService,
>   ETeismasServices.Cache.ICachedNotificationsStorage)'.

The dependency is registered in Autofac :

```
builder.RegisterType<CachedNotificationsStorage>().As<ICachedNotificationsStorage>();
```

And this is the CachedNotificationStorage constructor

```
public class CachedNotificationsStorage : ICachedNotificationsStorage
    {
        private readonly int itemsExpireMinutes;
        private const string NotificationsCacheKey = "Notifications";
        private readonly ObjectCache cache;

        public CachedNotificationsStorage()
        {
            itemsExpireMinutes = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["notificationsListItemsCahceExpirationInMinutes"]);
            cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            cache.Add(NotificationsCacheKey, new List<CachedNotificationsListItem>(), new CacheItemPolicy());
        }
        //.... logic etc
    }
```

So Autofac is trying to create a `NewProcessMessageHandler`
For that, Autofac needs to resolve an implementation of `ICachedNotificationStorage`.
There is a concrete implementation of `ICachedNotificationStorage` registered as `ICachedNotificationStorage`.

Why can't Autofac resolve it?
There is no magic in that constructor, it just adds an initial empty list to the cache.

NewProcessMessageHandler class :

```
public class NewProcessMessageHandler : BaseHandler<NewProcessMessage>
    {
        public NewProcessMessageHandler(IRepository repository, ICaseDelegationService caseDelegationService,
            IDocumentDelegationService documentDelegationService, ICachedNotificationsStorage cachedNotificationsStorage)
            : base(repository, caseDelegationService, documentDelegationService, cachedNotificationsStorage)
        {
        }
    }
```

And its base

```
public abstract class BaseHandler<T>: IHandleMessages<T>
{
    ...
    protected BaseHandler(IRepository repository, ICaseDelegationService caseDelegationService,
        IDocumentDelegationService documentDelegationService, ICachedNotificationsStorage cachedNotificationsStorage)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.caseDelegationService = caseDelegationService;
        this.documentDelegationService = documentDelegationService;
        this.cachedNotificationsStorage = cachedNotificationsStorage;
    }
...
}
```

Full code which performs the registration

```
private void StartNserviceBus()
        {
            SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(() => log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure());

            Configure.Transactions.Enable();
            Configure.Serialization.Xml();

            var builder = Behaviors.IoCServiceBehavior.CreateContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>()
                   .WithResolvedParameter((c, p) => new Lazy<ISession>(() => SessionFactory.Get().OpenSession()));

            builder.RegisterType<CaseDelegationService>().As<ICaseDelegationService>();
            builder.RegisterType<DocumentDelegationService>().As<IDocumentDelegationService>();
            builder.RegisterType<ChargesServiceStub>().As<IProjectChargesService>();
            builder.RegisterType<CachedNotificationsStorage>().As<ICachedNotificationsStorage>();
            builder.RegisterType<MeowDataOutputServiceClient>().As<IMeowDataOutputService>().AsWcfProxy();

            RegisterESBMessageHandlers(builder);
            container = builder.Build();

            Configure.With(AllAssemblies.Matching("ExternalServices.Contracts.ESB.").And("ProjectService"))
                     .DefineEndpointName("project_inbound")
                     .AutofacBuilder(container)
                     .UseTransport<Msmq>()
                     .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                     .DisableTimeoutManager()
                     .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                     .UnicastBus()
                     .ImpersonateSender(false)
                     .LoadMessageHandlers()
                     .DisableTimeoutManager()
#if DEBUG
                     .Log4Net()
#endif
                     .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("ExternalServices.Contracts.ESB"))
                     .CreateBus()
                     .Start(
                         () => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install()
                );
        }
```

RegisterESBMEssageHanlders() : the method registers 40+ message handlers

```
private  void RegisterESBMessageHandlers(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    ...40 of them handlers
    builder.RegisterType<EsbHandlers.NewPartyDocumentMessageHandler>().AsSelf();
    builder.RegisterType<EsbHandlers.NewProcessMessageHandler>().AsSelf();

}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure that this class is registered correctly? This error is simply, Autofac is not able to find this registration.

Comment: What do you mean - correctly?

Comment: How do you register your classes? Are you using [Modules](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html)? Can you share the code which performs the registration?

Comment: Could you share your `NewProcessHandler` with the constructor ?

Comment: This occurs on any Handler class, not just `NewProcessHandler`

Comment: @CyrilDurand added the handler code

Comment: @fknx added full registration code

Comment: I can't see any errors right now. Could you also share the `RegisterESBMessageHandlers` method ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand provided the sample of method. Sadly it looks good there too..

Comment: I have reporoduced the error in dev environment and dug up the actual error by debugging.. DeclaringMethod = error CS0433: 
The type 'Service' exists in both 'Autofac, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' 
and 'NServiceBus.Core, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c'

Comment: That was not it. Even though there was this error in DeclaringMethod, Autofac sill could resolve an instance for me. I have changed the way I pass the IContainer to NServiceBus configurator, and now it works. But I didn't really understand what was the cause of the error. The code ran in production for at least half a year and worked fine..